# Flow accumulation raster loading in QGIS 2.4.0 with null values (but flow direction loading ok!)

Tags: raster, arcmap, export, hydrology, qgis-2.4

I have been tasked with creating an open-source hydrology dataset for a community group. To do this I have exported the flow direction and flow accumulation rasters from ArcMap as TIFF files and then imported them into QGIS. However, a number of the flow accumulation rasters fail to import properly giving values of 0 rather than the range in the original ArcMap raster file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Flow accumulation usually stores very large numbers, because cell value= count of discharging cells. It is unlikely that tif is capable of storing values in this range

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree that they are large files with large numbers. However, one of the flow accumulation rasters loads with no problems (and covers a much larger geographical area) while two smaller ones fail. I've tried exporting from ArcMap in different formats and it still gives errors. Sigh.